# How to get rid of these bugs?

Tags: pest, insect

We have newly got these bugs at home and want to get rid of them. They are about 1 cm long. They live under a laminated "floating" floor and they are only active at night - they run around our washroom and one can easily step on them... Is there a way how to get rid of these without removing the floor?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That's a [silverfish](http://www.orkin.com/other/silverfish/). They're harmless to people and they won't do any structural damage to your home, but they do like to eat starch, cellulose, carbs; they'll do damage to wallpaper, book bindings, clothing, that kind of stuff. They like to eat mold and fungi too, and they tend to live in dark, moist / damp places.

As with any pest if you search around on the internet you can find a zillion suggestions for getting rid of them, some more successful than others.

Large infestations usually require an exterminator (if you find them problematic). But for small ones there are various things you can try first. [This article on WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Rid-of-Silverfish) has a number of suggestions, too many to reproduce here. [Here is another decent article](http://pestkill.org/insect/bugs/silverfish/), although it's fairly clear that the author really despises these bugs.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a silverfish, one of the most ancient pests to perturb humans. They don't bite, but there is anecdotal commentary related to the spread of germs.

Boric acid powder, used as directed, will help reduce their population.

Answer (score 0):

I agree - that is a silvefish.  Boric acid powder puffed into the nooks and crannies of the area is a safe (if slightly slow) way to get rid of them.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement.  Just a heads up, the site is a knowledge base of solutions rather than a forum.  The objective is to have answer posts that each provide a solution to the original question that hasn't already been contributed.  So posts that just confirm another answer without adding something substantive to it aren't really considered answers in this format.  The way we do that is to upvote good answers (which you'll be able to do with a small amount of rep from upvotes on your own good answers).